# Custom Class of property added to a List

Tags: vb.net, winforms, list

This seems like something I should know, and maybe it's working fine but it looks wrong to me.  I'm looking to add some data from a database query into a list which I've created a custom class of properties to hold.

My class:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private _Col1 As String
    Private _Col2 As String
    Private _Col3(,) As Object
    Private _Col4 As String

    Public Property Col1() As String
        Get
            Return _Col1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Col1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Col2() As String
        Get
            Return Col2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Col2= value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Col3() As Object(,)
        Get
            Return Col3
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object(,))
            Col3= value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Col4() As String
        Get
            Return Col4
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Col4= value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New(ByVal col1 As String, ByVal col2 As String, ByVal col3 As Object, ByVal col4 As String)
        _Col1= col1
        _Col2= col2
        _Col3 = col3
        _Col4 = col4

    End Sub

 End Class
```

When I declare and initialize my List(of Class) and then add data to it:

```
Dim NList as New List(Of MyClass)

NList.Add(New MyClass("1", "2", (1,3), "3"))
```

When I take a look at the List item, I am seeing 8 items inside the list instead of 4. 4 are the methods in there, and 4 are the variables.  Is this correct and how class properties act?  It seems like I am wasting resources by adding data to the 4 variables and if I have to loop through a recordset that has 40k rows I am assuming it would add to performance.  Is this the correct way it works?  I plan on adding items to the list and using the Find() function later in the program so I feel that 8 items instead of 4 is un needed.

Edit: The list items

```
?NList.Item(0)
    _Col1: "1" {String}
    _Col2: "2"
    _Col3: "(1,3)"
    _Col4: "4"
    Col3: "(1,3)"
    Col4: "4"
    Col1: "1"
    Col2: "2"
```

Comment: when you `look at the List item` you are looking at an instance of `MyClass` not the `items inside the list`  that one line of code will add one item to the list, you are probably seeing the private backing fields as well as the properties.  (Per Edit) obviously the case: `_Col1` is your private backing field and `Col1` is the property.  Note newer VS versions allow auto implemented props so that `Public Property Col1() As String` is all you need in many cases which will greatly reduce the class code

Comment: Are both of those getting populated while going to the class?  Won't this affect performance if we are iterating through the rows and adding them to this list?

Comment: there is only one thing being set: `_col1`, look at the code for `Property Col1()` it just sets or returns that same value

Comment: Ok you are right, if you wouldn't mind posting an answer so i could accept it.  Thanks much

Comment: actually, your getters and setters are wrong for Col2, 3 and 4: they should reference the backing fields (_ColX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private _Col1 As String    ' private backing field to hold the value

    ' interface to get/set that same value
    Public Property Col1() As String
        Get
            Return _Col1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Col1 = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Your class will only have one variable for that property value.  In your debug, you are seeing both the backing fields and the property interface:

```
?NList.Item(0)
    _Col1: "1" {String}        <== backing field storing the value
    ...
    Col1: "1"                  <== property 'exposing' _Col1
```

Note that your class can be greatly simplified using auto implemented properties and forgo explicit backing fields:

```
Public Class fooClass
    Public Property Col1() As String
    Public Property Col2() As String
    Public Property Col3() As DateTime
    Public Property Col4() As Integer

    ' VS creates hidden backing fields you can still reference in the class:
    Public Sub New(str As String ...)
        _Col1 = str
        ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly normal behaviour. Those variables with an underscore are the class's member variables. They are actually containing your data. Your properties on the other hand, do not hold any data at all. You can think of them as functions which return your member variables to a caller. You can see their return values in your direct prompt too, because they are visually treated like normal variables.

Using member variables and properties together is the common approach when programming .Net.
If you are not executing any additional code in your properties you can just write:

```
Public Property MyProperty As SomeType
```

In this case the compiler automatically generates an invisible corresponding member variable for you.

Answer (score 1):

I modified you sample code a bit.  Maybe this will help?

```
Public Class TestClass
    Public Property Col1 As String
    Public Property Col2 As String
    Public Property Col3 As Object
    Public Property Col4 As String
End Class
```

Add items to the list like this

```
    Dim NList As New List(Of TestClass)

    NList.Add(New TestClass With {.Col1 = "1", .Col2 = "2", .Col3 = "3", .Col4 = "4"})
    NList.Add(New TestClass With {.Col1 = "A", .Col2 = "B", .Col3 = "C", .Col4 = "D"})
```